# Idiomatic multiindex column assignment in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a 2-level Multiindex:

```
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(enumerate(np.random.choice(['A', 'B'], 5))))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Val': np.random.randint(0, 30, 5)}, index=ix).unstack().fillna(0)
df
   Val    
     A   B
0   27   0
1    0   3
2    0   7
3    9   0
4    0  19
```

I would like to add a column for each existing sublevel (`'A'` and `'B'`) that is equal to half of the `Val` column. My intuition was to do

```
df['Half_val'] = df.Val / 2
```

which gives a `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1` exception.

I can manually do

```
res = df.Val / 2
df.loc[:, ('Half_val', 'A')] = res.A
df.loc[:, ('Half_val', 'B')] = res.B
```

which gives what I'm after:

```
>>> df
   Val      Half_val     
     A   B         A    B
0   27   0      13.5  0.0
1    0   3       0.0  1.5
2    0   7       0.0  3.5
3    9   0       4.5  0.0
4    0  19       0.0  9.5
```

Is there a less verbose, more idiomatic way to make a multiindex column assignment like this (particularly one where I don't have to explicitly specify each sublevel on the left side)?

Edit:

I forgot to mention that trying

```
res = df.Val / 2
df.loc[:, res.columns] = res
```

gives a `KeyError: "['A' 'B'] not in index"` exception.

**Edit 2**
It would be nice if the solution allowed pseudo-mixed level columns in the dataframe. In my example, I can do

```
In [5]: df['C'] = 'a'
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   Val      C
     A   B
0    4   0  a
1    0  10  a
2    0   4  a
3   21   0  a
4    0  14  a
```

which adds a column with a single level. But since the column already had 2 levels, it appears it gives an implicit second level of an empty string

```
In [9]: list(df)
Out[9]: [('Val', 'A'), ('Val', 'B'), ('C', '')]
```

when I try a solution offered below, it the single-level `C` column seems to break it:

```
In [7]: pd.concat([df,df['Val']/2],axis=1,keys=['Val', 'C', 'Half'])
==> AssertionError: Cannot concat indices that do not have the same number of levels
```

Is there some trick for the `keys` parameter to pass, or do I need to give `C` a different dummy value for the second level (since it looks like `""` doesn't count) and then remove it after the concatenation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the level values and do a direct assignment (one value at a time)

```
In [55]: df.columns.get_level_values(1)
Out[55]: Index([u'A', u'B'], dtype='object')

In [51]: df[('Half','A')] = df[('Val','A')]/2

In [52]: df[('Half','B')] = df[('Val','B')]/2

In [53]: df
Out[53]: 
   Val      Half      
     A   B     A     B
0    0  12   0.0   6.0
1    0   5   0.0   2.5
2    0  26   0.0  13.0
3    3   0   1.5   0.0
4   25   0  12.5   0.0
```

You can do this as well

```
In [59]: concat([df['Val'],df['Val']/2],axis=1,keys=['Val','Half'])
Out[59]: 
   Val      Half        
     A   B     A    B
0    0  10   0.0  5.0
1    0  10   0.0  5.0
2    0  13   0.0  6.5
3   27   0  13.5  0.0
4    2   0   1.0  0.0
```

Here's an issue to track this bug/enhancement: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7475

Comment: I like the `concat` solution. I neglected to mention that I have other columns in my particular dataframe with a single level (say call `df['C'] = 'a'` in my example above). When I try doing `pd.concat([df,df['Val']/2],axis=1,keys=['Val', 'C', 'Half'])` I get `AssertionError: Cannot concat indices that do not have the same number of levels`. Is this a fundamental limitation of concat?

Comment: that doesn't make sense to do. As its ambiguous how to combine non-equal levels.

Comment: You mean it doesn't make sense to have a mixed level dataframe in the first place, or just to combine it with a 2-level df?

Comment: yes, mixed level frames are not allowed at all (but levels can be ''). and then *where* to combine it with something else is ambiguous (e.g. which level are you aligning).

Answer (score 2):

I think this option is preferable to the concat option because you don't have to risk incorrectly re-labeling the 'Val' column.  Please correct me if you disagree!

Given your input dataframe:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
  Val
    A   B
0  26   0
1  10   0
2  18   0
3   0  18
4   2   0
```

A third option worth considering is:

```
In [4]: df[pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Half']] + df.columns.levels[1:])] = df['Val'] / 2

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
  Val     Half
    A   B    A  B
0  26   0   13  0
1  10   0    5  0
2  18   0    9  0
3   0  18    0  9
4   2   0    1  0
```

This approach also just works with an arbitrarily nested MultiIndex.  (I don't know if it's possible do this assignment with sub-columns of a MultiIndex).

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Val': np.random.randint(5, 30, 12)}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B','C'], ['a', 'b'], [0, 1]])).unstack().unstack()

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
  Val
    0       1
    a   b   a   b
A   6  10  11   7
B  16   8  23  15
C  29  17  11  18

In [3]: df[pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Half']] + df.columns.levels[1:])] = df['Val'] / 2

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
  Val              Half
    0       1         0          1
    a   b   a   b     a    b     a    b
A   6  10  11   7   3.0  5.0   5.5  3.5
B  16   8  23  15   8.0  4.0  11.5  7.5
C  29  17  11  18  14.5  8.5   5.5  9.0
```

Comment: Actually this can be made a bit more general. Take the columns from the new dataframe and use them in the MultiIndex: `half = df['Val']/2; df[pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Half'],list(half.columns)])] = half`.